# How does Guice Populate Annotated Fields

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

For the sake of my own education, I wanted to build a simple Dependency Injection framework that functions similar to the way Google's Guice does. So that when a class is loaded, it pre-populates annotated fields with data from a factory class.

I am using Reflections to scan all my factory classes at compile time and save those classes in a static list so that when it comes time to load my classes, I have a reference to my factories that I can then scan methods and return the appropriate data.

Where i'm stuck at is how to pre-populate my classes annotated fields without actually doing any of the work in the actual class. In other words, when a class is loaded, I need to be able to determine if any of the fields are annotated with a specific annotation, and if they are, retrieve the value from the factory class.

Is there some way of performing reflection on a class right before it is loaded, pre-populate specific fields and then return an instance of that class to be used?

I could extend all of my classes that require dependency injection with a base class that does all of this work, but I figure there must be a better way so that I can simply use an @Inject (or whatever annotation I decide to use to say that this field requires DI) and "magically" all the work is done.

Comment: You cannot find annotated fields without loading a class using the basic reflection Java API. Also, injection is done after calling the constructor of an object. Take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that Guice approaches this is that it will only populate the fields of an instance **that was itself created by Guice**<sup>1</sup>.  The injector, after creating the instance, can use the Reflection API to look at the fields of the `Class` and inspect their annotations with [`Field.getDeclaredAnnotations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaredAnnotations%28%29).

This is also the reason why, when you want to inject into a static field, you need to use [`Binder.requestStaticInjection()`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29) to populate the static fields.

Guice does not simply scan your code for annotations; all injections recurse from an explicit request (e.g. `requestStaticInjection()`, `Injector.getInstance()`, etc).  Now often that initial, explicit request will have been made in some library code.

For example, if you're using `guice-servlet` you let Guice create the instances of your servlet by using the `serve().with()` calls.  But if you didn't do that, and instead left your servlet config in your `web.xml`, Guice would not inject into your servlet.

<sup>1 - You can also request explicit injection using `Binder.requestInjection()`.</sup>

Comment: So currently I use an injector object (my own, I am just trying to replicate a minimal version of Guice as a learning experience) which is defined in my servlet config class. It scans all classes marked as a factory with Reflections and stores those classes in a static variable. Would I then define variables like String testString = Injector.getDependencyInstance("testString")?

Comment: No, you can set the values using Field.set()